# Find all $n$ $( n \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$ that satisfy this condition

Tags: number-theory

Find all $n$ $( n \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$ such that:- $$n = 2(f(n))^2$$ where $f(n)$ is a function of the sum of all digits of $n$.

Comment: This year's Indian RMO problem?You should also show how you reached the conclusion

Comment: Its not actually a solution, so I'll mention in the comments. I rewrote n as:-

Comment: You also know that $n\leq3200$, since if $10000>n>1000$, then $f(n)<40$, so $2f(n)^2<2\cdot 40^2=3200$.

Comment: $a.10^m + b.10^{m-1}.........$.Therefore,$a.10^m + b.10^{m-1}.........x.10 + y = 2(a+b.......x+y)^2$ .Since, $f(n)^2$ divides $n$, $(a+b.......x+y)$ divides $a.10^m + b.10^{m-1}.........$. Since $a < (a+b.......x+y)$, $(a+b.......x+y)$ cannot divide $a$ and therefore must divide $10^m$ . Therefore, $(a+b.......x+y)$ is of the form $2^{2c}.5^{2d}.$Therefore,$a.10^m + b.10^{m-1}.........$ is of the form $2^{2c+1}.5^{2d}.$

Comment: @5xum, but $n$ is not given to be less than $10000$ or greater than $1000$. The question says its a number in base 10.

Comment: @Lucifer- Sure, I am just telling you that if you want to brute force check it, you only need to check the first 3200 numbers.

Comment: @Lucifer- Also, the number $162$ shows that you are incorrect thinking that the number is of the form $2^x5^y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46729/discussion-between-lucifer-and-5xum).

Comment: @5xum-I found a solution somewhere but I can understand it. I'll include it in the question so can you help me with it?

Comment: @Lucifer please add the given solution

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I'll be uploading it soon. The solution is lengthy and requires lot of MathJax coding. So it would take some time for me to code it.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN. I got it. The link is -https://www.iitianspace.com/images/RMO%20Solutions%20_10-10-16_%20_1_.pdf . I'll post the solution.